# How can i sort the column containing date difference using datatables?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, date, datatables

I have a column in table that contains data like:

```
1 year 5 months 12 days
7 months
3 year 4 days
```

I want to sort this column. How can I do this?

Comment: please put your code here whish you have done so far

Comment: i just have a html table showing data from php. I have to apply sorting on the column stated above. the only js i have done on datatables is :                        $('#actionData').DataTable({
        paging: false, // Disable default pagination
        searching: false, // Disable default searching
        stateSave: true, // Save table sort state for reloads
        info: false       // Hide table information
    });

Comment: Btw, we can not provide solution without your code, here are can not read your mind for what you have done. :)

Comment: What code should i provide?

Comment: Some code of PHP or HTML and put it in your Question description.

Answer (score 3):

Check this article about [Orthrogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) from DataTables manual.

Let's say you have a table with 3 columns and the third column holds the date-related data you want to sort.

Try providing your data in this format:

```
// Array with data objects
var data = [
   {
      "column1": "column1_data",
      "column2": "column2_data",
      "column3": {
          "display": "1 year",
          // Convert '1 year' to 777600000 (or try your own convertion algorithm)
          "timestamp": "777600000"
      }
   },
   {
      "column1": "column1_data",
      "column2": "column2_data",
      "column3": {
          "display": "1 month",
          "timestamp": "12960000"
      }
   },
   .....
]
```

Then, in DataTables initialization try this:

```
$('#myTable').DataTables({
   ....
   "columns": [
       { data: "column1" },
       { data: "column2" },
       { 
         data: "column3",
         render: {
            _: 'display',
            sort: 'timestamp'
         }
       }
   ],
   ....
});
```

In this way, you display the date in a non sortable format (1 year, 5 months etc), but you sort this column by 'timstamp' attribute.

All you have to do is to convert the literal representation of the date data into a common comparable format and provide the data array.

---

**DATE CONVERTION PROPOSAL**

You are merely converting the literal representation of time range into seconds

```
/**
*  Function that convert a literal (n text) in to a number representing a timestamp
*/ @param literal {string} Text in specific format (n text): n {number} [blank] text {string} ('year','month','day','hour','minute','second')
*/
function convertLiteralToTimeSpan(literal) {
    ....
}
```

```js
    function convertLiteralToTimeSpan(literal) {
        var textObj = {
           'second': '1',
           'minute': '60',
           'hour': '3600',
           'day': '216000',
           'month': '12960000',
           'year': '777600000'
        };
        var literalArr = literal.split(' ');
        var num = literalArr [0];
        var txt = literalArr [1];
        var factor = textObj[txt];
        
        return parseInt(num) * parseInt(factor);
    }

    var test = convertLiteralToTimeSpan('1 year');
    var test_month = convertLiteralToTimeSpan('1 month');
    var test_day = convertLiteralToTimeSpan('1 day');

    $('#result').html(test);
    $('#result_month').html(test_month);
    $('#result_day').html(test_day);
```

```css
.result { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1 year</span>: <span id="result" class="result"></span><br />
<span>1 month</span>: <span id="result_month" class="result"></span><br />
<span>1 day</span>: <span id="result_day" class="result"></span>
```